# Elastic Beanstalk Amazon linux 2 with docker | nginx custom configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I am configuring aws elasticbeanstalk Amazon linux 2 with docker-compose.
I want to configure nginx like this.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location /admin {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

So i just followed above docs. And my source code package directory architecture is as below.

```
.ebextensions
.platform
   nginx
       conf.d
           myconf.conf
docker-compose.yml
```

After deployment, when i access my elastic beanstalk url, there were 502 gateway error.
When i checked elastic beanstalk(ec2), my docker container was running successfully. And i could access localhost:3000 in my ec2 container.

I want to adopt my custom nginx configuration on elasticbeanstalk Amazon Linux 2 enviornment, and i followed the settings in the documentation[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html], but it didn't work.

How can i adopt my custom nginx configuration on elasticbeanstlak Amazon Linux 2? Is there any process i was missing?